# How do I import a single component from this library?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs, rsuite

I'd like to understand how to use Babel, webpack or whatever the tool I need to import a single component from a library.

Here https://rsuitejs.com/en/guide/usage when you scroll down to  'Use modularized rsuite' they say that I need to install `babel-preset-rsuite` and then add a `.babelrc` file, but with this in it:

```
{
  "presets": ["rsuite"]
}
```

I've done it, and it still does not import the .less styles. So I end up with an HTML button without the nice styling that goes with it.

(I'm a bit titled, have tried every possible thing and nothing works, I just broke my entire codebase because of another webpack issue, fortunately I was able to recover it thanks to my VCS)

Can someone, please, explain the beginner that I am what exactly do I have to do? Do I have to run a specific command instead of `react-scripts start` so that it takes this .babelrc file into account?

Thanks

Comment: This is a professional Q/A site. Such words are not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OFF:

To use a single component from a library:

1. Install a library
2. Import the necessary component:

   import { Example } from 'example-installed-library'

ON:

And related to babel, I recommend this article to read:
https://www.valentinog.com/blog/react-webpack-babel/

And of course it's own site with documentation: https://babeljs.io/

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look

Answer (score 0):

By not introducing less by default, you need to configure `style: true`.

```
{
    "presets": [["rsuite", { style: true }]]
}
```